# Desire sv does not start after clear cache

Tags: htc-desire, boot, cache

I cleared cache memory of my HTC Desire SV then tried to restart the phone. It does not start. I have also tried hard boot on this phone but result is same.

How can I get my phone to boot again?

Comment: What method did you use to clear your cache? (ClockWorkMod/TWRP Recovery? ROM Manager? Other?) What steps did you use to hard-boot the phone?

Answer (score 0):

My phone is working now.I have followed steps to bring my phone up :

1. Removed battery from phone for 30-40 minutes.
2. Insert battery to slot and press power-on button, that's it.

"Now, I don't bother about root cause "